# Add subdivision to a geometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying add subdivisions to a sphere like this:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Subdivision-Cube.html

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mdrorum/HvFLw/

```
        <script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/build/three.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var geometry, material, mesh;
            var smooth, subdiv, modifier;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 1000;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200 );
                material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                var smooth = mesh.clone();
                var subdiv = 3;
                var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier( subdiv );
                //modifier.modify( smooth );


            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
```

This works fine, but uncomment: `//modifier.modify( smooth );`

Nothing happens. :(

How I can add subdivisions?

Comment: Do you get any error? (Look at your JavaScript error console.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to modify a `mesh`. You need to modify a `geometry`.

```
modifier.modify( geometry );
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2011/11/06/subdivision-surfaces-with-three-js/) you can find a good tutorial with a working [demo](http://client.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog_examples/html5-webgl-subdivision/). Citing the author:

```
// First we want to clone our original geometry.
// Just in case we want to get the low poly version back.
var smooth = THREE.GeometryUtils.clone( geometry );

// Next, we need to merge vertices to clean up any unwanted vertex. 
smooth.mergeVertices();

// Create a new instance of the modifier and pass the number of divisions.
var divisions = 3;
var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(divisions);

// Apply the modifier to our cloned geometry.
modifier.modify( smooth );

// Finally, add our new detailed geometry to a mesh object and add it to our scene.
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( smooth, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x222222 } ) );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: Now days it's just geo.clone() and SubdivisionModifier has to be referenced from a separate script source located in a modifiers folder. Unfortunately both that and the Buffered one are failing to function correctly with my Blender exported obj despite a few quick hacks to correct hard failures of missing arrays in those files.