# Three.js subdivision modifier on json object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a technique to transforming my lower polygon model into a more detailed model.

How do I add a subdivision modifier to my json object?

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

  var group = new THREE.Object3D();

   loader.load('/models/model.js', function(geometry){
     var mymodel = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
     mymodel .position.set( 0, 0.002, 0 );
     mymodel .rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 0.67, 0 );
     mymodel .scale.set( 0.085, 0.085, 0.085 );
     group.add( mymodel );
   });




  scene.add( group );
```

Comment: Have you googled it ? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html , https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Subdivision-Cube.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add subdivision to a geometry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880497/add-subdivision-to-a-geometry)